# Service request/response: would you use routing keys and store messages in the same RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, soa, microservices

For example, I've implemented a search indexing service, which receives search requests and produces responses using messages.

Currently I've defined a queue to enqueue *search requests* and other one to enqueue *search results*.

Would you refactor this to just enqueue to an unique queue where messages have a *request* and *response* **routing keys**? Or is this overusing *RabbitMQ* on this particular case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I feel that this should be a *good practice*:

- There should be a single exchange. For example **searchrequest**.
- Two queues, one for *incoming* requests and other for *responses*.
- The whole single exchange should route message from requests or responses queue based on a given routing key.
- When some service does a search requests, sends a message to **searchrequest** exchange and **request** routing key. When search indexing service creates a response, sends it to **searchrequest** exchange too but it publishes the response message with **response** routing key.

At the end of the day, using routing keys to publish messages to same queue on my particular case doesn't seem to be *natural*. It feels hacky.

Comment: Check this out [from Udi Dahan](http://udidahan.com/2011/03/20/careful-with-content-based-routing/)

Comment: @SeanFarmar Good article. Well, it's not a rule (*don't use ESB routing*) but I'm aware that routing can be abused. I find that my own answer is a good practice, because at the end of the day you still deploy two queues and the *exchange* acts like an ESB namespace. What's your point on this?

Comment: I'm in favour of simplicity and separating channels, It sounds natural to me to have (in the scenario you described) search command processor and a search result processor, once the search command processor completes its work it will send a search result command with the indexed data, the search result processor will do whatever it needs to do in order to do it's job... Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use the RPC pattern? To follow the protocol, you should publish the response based on the `ReplyTo` or `ReplyToAddress` from the `BasicProperties`. That way, it is up to the caller (requester) to decided where the response is expected to be published. In my opinion it might be overkill to declare a dedicated exchange for one message type. For higher performance, you could use the [direct reply to](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html) feature. There are [a lot of high level clients](http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html) that helps you deal with some of these things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It adds more details to my concern. BTW, I believe that my auto-answer fits better in my domain, because I need ACK. But it's good to know that for other cases there's a build-in approach!